# Equation of parabola in x-y plane

Tags: linear-algebra, analytic-geometry

[image]

Given the following equations:

$$x=t^2$$

$$y=t^2$$

$$z=2t+3$$

Show that the graph of the curve $(t^2,t^2,2t+3)$ lives in a plane and that, within that plane, the graph is a parabola.

My attempt, so far:

From the first two equations $x=y$, meaning the curve belongs to the  $x-y=0$ plane.

Plugging the first or second equation into the third one:

$$((z-3)/2)^2=x,\>\>\> ((z-3)/2)^2=y$$

This tells me it is parabola in the zx and zy planes respectively , I guess ??

A matlab plot shows it is , in fact, a parabola in the $x-y=0$  plane. What I am doing wrong and how do I show it?

Comment: That's a space curve, not a plane curve.

Comment: @lulu Well, it lies in the plane $x=y$ so it is also a plane curve.

Comment: “... $x=y$, meaning the curve belongs to the $x$-$y$ plane.” No, it doesn’t. Continuing, the only way that a curve can lie in both the $x$-$z$ and $y$-$z$ planes is if it lies entirely on the $z$-axis, in which case this isn’t a parabola.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown  True, I was just writing a comment to that effect.  But it is not in the $xy-$plane.

Comment: It's not in the $xy$-plane, it's in a plane perpendicular to that and at angle $\pi/4$ to the $xz$ and $yz$-planes.

Comment: I think the question should read:  show that the graph of the curve $\vec r(t)=(t^2,t^2, 2t+3)$ lives in a plane and that, within that plane, the graph is a parabola.

Comment: @ lulu, Yes ,that is what I meant.

Comment: The $xy$-plane is where $z=0$, which is not the case here. Instead, call it the $x=y$ plane, or the plane spanned by $\{[1,1,0],[0,0,1]\}$, or the description that Lord Shark gave above.

Comment: Sorry I did mean the x=y plane: x-y=0. I added the =0 for clarity

Answer (score 1):

Rotate the $xyz$-coordinates by 45 degrees around the $z$ axis to the $uvz$-coordinates, which is equivalent to

$$x=u+v, \>\>\> y=u-v$$

Rewrite the curve in the $uv$-coordinates

$$u+v=t^2, \>\>\>u-v=t^2$$

Then, we have $u=t^2$ and $v=0$. So, the curve lies in the plane $v=0$, with the $uz$ coordinates given by,

$$u = t^2$$
$$z=2t+3$$

Eliminate $t$ to get the standard parabola equation in the plane $v=0$ (or, the plane $x=y$ in the original coordinates)

$$(z-3)^2=4u$$

Comment: what if the plane were not that simple as to determine the rotation angle? Can you give a simpler solution?

Comment: One could always find a general spherical rotation $(\theta, \phi)$ as long as the parabola in a plane. The result may not be as simple as this one.

Comment: Can you detail how to find the transformation equations? and how do you show that the curve lives in a plane to start with?

Comment: The actual rotation would very much depend on the curve in question. See for example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_of_axes for details of Cartesian axis rotation.

Answer (score 0):

If a curve $u(t)$ lies on a plane, then the plane defined by any three points $A$, $B$, $C$ on the curve must be always the same, i.e. the vector product 
$\vec n=(B-A)\times(C-A)$ must have the same direction for any choice of the points.

In practice we can keep two points fixed and choose, for instance: $A=u(0)=(0,0,3)$, $B=u(1)=(1,1,5)$, $C=u(t)=(t^2,t^2,2t+3)$, to find:
$$
\vec n=(1,1,2)\times(t^2,t^2,2t)=(2t-t^2,2t-t^2,0)=(2t-t^2)(1,1,0).
$$
The direction $\vec n/|\vec n|$ is then ${1\over\sqrt2}(1,1,0)$ and does not depend on $t$: hence the curve lies on a plane whose normal unit vector is ${1\over\sqrt2}(1,1,0)$.